# Surname Reg Expression with wild card

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a text box with a reg expression that would allow Characters, apostrophes, hyphens and wildcards (* and ?).

I have found `^[\p{L} \.'\-]+$` which should allow the characters, apostrophes and hypens.  What would I need to add to accept the wildcards as well?

Comment: JavaScript does not natively support Unicode properties like `\p{L}`. You'd need the XRegExp package for this.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you consider ok and one of what you don't?

Comment: Can I use [a-zA-Z] for the characters then?

Comment: acceptable would be howard-smi*  or mi?th or O'Neil or McGe*  Not acceptable would would be any numerics or any other special characters apart from * and ? .

Comment: So `Peña`, `Ørsted` or `Bublé` would not be OK, then?

Comment: I suppose they would be.  Basically looking for a reg expression that would check surnames with wild cards.

Comment: You might want to read [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) and then decide not to try and validate a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to validate:

```
[A-Za-z'\-*?]+
```

Inside the square brackets ? and * are not special chars.

If you need to match the whole string do

```
^[A-Za-z'\-*?]+$
```

Comment: '-' is a special character in regex character classes - your regex is going to match everything "between" "'" and "*"... escape it or put it at the end of the class to solve...

Comment: You are right, I'm the blindest regex tester over the world... thanks

Comment: Only allows ASCII letters. Comments to the question suggest that that's not enough.

Comment: Thanks. I allowed only ascii letters because this was the initial request

Comment: @TimPietzcker However, edit after edit, I'm sloowly slipping towards  agreeing with your last comment on the question

Comment: @Gabber: `\w` only knows ASCII in JavaScript, and now you're allowing digits too, which Kev explicitly disallows.

Comment: Right again, didn't think about javascript and didn't think about digits, I'll return to my first solution